# Uniswap V3 about price range and swap details

Tags: cryptocurrency

I've been using Uniswap for 2 days, and I have a question about the price range. If my liquidity is out of range, does that mean during that time my allocation to the pool's assets get locked regardless of the pricing going up or down dramatically?

ie., if the time my price range is moving out of the current price, I had 1 ETH and 3500 DAI, then the pool keeps working and the allocation of those two coins are changed, later if I choose to remove will I get 1 ETH and 3500 DAI or my allocation will be prorated based on my ownership of the pool?

48 hours ago I put ETH/USDC and I only set one price range on USDC, I thought ETH will be set same percent, and last night I checked I have no ETH left, what happened? Could you let me know the theoretical principals behind this?

Appreciated! CB

Answer (score 1):

There could be 2 explanations:

1. You set a narrow range, the ETH price rose, and moved out of your range. Hence all of your ETH were converted to USDC, as explained [here](https://uniswap.org/blog/uniswap-v3/#active-liquidity)
2. You used a [range order](https://uniswap.org/blog/uniswap-v3/#active-liquidity), so that you effectively sold your ETH for DAI